# Nginx location rewrite behind a proxy is not working

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am creating a simple nginx web server. There are a few php files and some static pages, and I have separated them into different folders, the php files in /data/webjp and the html files in /data/webjp_static .  Here is the configuration file:

```
server
{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:7900/;
        proxy_store             on;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server
{
    listen       7900;

    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    root  /data/webjp/weber;
    index index.html index.php;

    location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
    {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/webjp/weber/index.php;
    }

    location ~ /erarticles/ {
        root /data/webjp_static;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    location ~* \.html$ {
        expires -1;
    }
}
```

It seems that the "location ~ /erarticles/" block is not working. When I tried to access http://192.168.1.118/erarticles/56b1be02e33f6e3c6f000000/2016001.html, I got 404.

But if I put the "location ~ /erarticles/" block in the proxy server block, it did works. Why?

After read the answer from Richard Smith, I found a clue. In fact, my project is working with Yii framework, and I omitted a few lines of the  configuration file when I posted it here.

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your configuration looks rather odd. It isn't clear to me what you are actually trying to accomplish here. You tell that you have some PHP files, but you are passing all PHP requests to `index.php` with your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter. Also the fact that you match all files with extensions `.`, `.php` and `.php5` with your PHP `location` block looks odd. Furthermore, I don't understand why you are proxying the request in the first place... You should fix the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the reverse proxy. The server block for 7900 has multiple issues.

The default document root is set to the PHP directory, so that the `location ~* \.html$` block can never work.

I do not know what `if (-f $request_filename) { break; }` is supposed to do.

And the `location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$` block matches URIs like `.`. You state that you have some `.php` files, but you only return `index.php`.

Have you considered using `try_files`? For example (and this is only a starting point):

```
server {
    listen       7900;

    root /data/webjp_static;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php5?$ {
        root  /data/webjp/weber;
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }

    location ~* \.html$ {
        expires -1;
    }
}
```

Note that the `index` directive will not find any `index.php` files as you keep them in a separate directory from the `.html` files.

Read [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) first.

Comment: Awsome! Thank you very much. I learned a lot from your answer.